# How to .wrap() items in .map() function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Can anyone explain to me how to wrap elements in a .map() function? I want to output it in a list. So the values need to be wrapped in the list item tag. I experimented with the .map(), .wrap() and even the .each(). No luck.

Please check out this Fiddle for more info: https://jsfiddle.net/mjcu8teq/

```
$('.product-info-checkbox-container .custom-checkbox').change(function () {

    var countChecked = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;

    // check if one or more of the checkboxes is checked 
    if (countChecked != 0) {

        var checkbox_array = $('.product-info-checkbox-container .custom-checkbox:checked').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get();

        $('.destination ul').html(checkbox_array.join(', '));

    }
});
```

Comment: .wrap doesn't work on an array of strings, so you'll of course have to modify your .join() to have it result in html. or have the .map directly return html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this:

```
$('.destination ul').html(checkbox_array.join(', '));
```

to this:

```
$('.destination ul').html('<li>' + checkbox_array.join('</li><li>') + '</li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/x7h8skh0/

```
$('.product-info-checkbox-container .custom-checkbox').change(function () {
var finalhtml = '';
    $('input:checked').each(function(index, checkboxelement) {
        finalhtml += '<li>' + $(checkboxelement).val() + '</li>';
    });
        $('.destination ul').html(finalhtml);


});
```